# Best way to store state space in python

Tags: python, tree, reinforcement-learning

So I'm trying to implement a reinforcement learning agent that plays tic-tac-toe. To do this, I need to create a data structure that stores the state of the game, the actions available at that state, and the reward for taking said actions given that state. Also, it has to be able to return the maximum reward of taking an available action given the state. Specifically, the state of the game here is given by a 9-vector that can have the values 0,1,2 (empty,player 1, player2). There are up to 9 possible actions to be taken at each step (Less if those squares have already been occupied)

I've come up with this:

```
    #Input np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]),1
class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=defaultdict(nested_dict)
    def set(self,key,key2,value):        
        self.data[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]][key[3]][key[4]][key[5]][key[6]][key[7]][key[8]][key2]=value
    def get(self,key,key2=''):
        if(key2==''):
             return self.data[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]][key[3]][key[4]][key[5]][key[6]][key[7]][key[8]]
        return self.data[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]][key[3]][key[4]][key[5]][key[6]][key[7]][key[8]][key2]
    def get_max_child(self,state):
        return np.max(list(a.get(state).values()))
#Example of use
a=Tree()
a.set([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],7,1)
a.set([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],6,2)
a.get_max_child([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
#Returns 2
```

How could this be made better? Some restrictions I am imposing myself are:

1. Not precalculating all possible states and assigning them an
   integer
2. I want to do this with a lookup table, not a neural network. That will come later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end a dictionary of tuples a={(state,action):value} works